# Access web.config key from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a key in the web.config file like:

```
<add key="MailFrom" value="my@email.com"/>
```

I need to access it in the code behind.How to do this in c#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) property indexer:

```
string from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailFrom"];
```

Comment: Most projects, don't seem to have a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` by default, which is required to access `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, even though parts of the `System.Configuration` namespace are available without it. Worth mentioning for anyone that comes across this question but for a non-WebForms project (as WebForms seems to reference it for you).

Comment: @Rob, good remark. The link I provided to the documentation states exactly in which assembly this method is located so if the reader takes his time to check it out there won't be any problems.